# For $n > 2, n \in \mathbb{Z}$, show the sum of integers coprime to $n$ in the range $[1,n-1]$ is equal to $\frac{1}{2}n \phi(n)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

> For $n > 2, n \in \mathbb{Z}$, show the sum of integers coprime to $n$ in the range $[1,n-1]$ is equal to $\frac{1}{2}n \phi(n)$

Firstly $\phi(n)$ is Euler's totient function, the number of integers that are coprime to $n$ for $1 \leq x < n$.

The way I was going about answering this question was considering $n-x$, where $n - x$ (mod $n$) $\equiv - x$ (mod $n$), and as gcd($-x,n$) = 1 they share similar properties, but are not the same ie. $x \neq n-x$ (which I struggled to prove rigorously).

I'm really struggling to think of any other options or how it ends up being the expected value to the sum.

Thanks,

Comment: This $\phi(x)$ should be $\phi(n)$

Comment: $x\ne n-x$ because $x=n-x$ implies $x$ is a divisor of $n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $A=\{a_1,a_2......a_{\phi(n)}\}$ be set of integers less than and coprime to $n$. Now consider the set $\{n-a_1,n-a_2......n-a_{\phi(n)}\}$ then this set also consist of elements which are less than and coprime to $n$.

So $A=\{n-a_1,n-a_2......n-a_{\phi(n)}\}$.

and therefore sum

$S=a_1+a_2......+a_{\phi(n)}. . . . (1)$

$S=n-a_1+n-a_2+......+n-a_{\phi(n)}. . . . (2)$

adding equation (1) and (2) we have

$2S=n\phi(n)$

So $S=\frac{1}{2}n\phi(n)$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use the trick Gauss used when he was a baby to find the sum of the integers from $1$ to $M$.

List the numbers in our interval that are relatively prime to $n$, list them backwards, and add. Note that $\gcd(k,n)=1$ if and only if $\gcd(n-k,n)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The sum equals $\frac12n\phi(n)$ if the average is $\frac12n$.
You have found you can sort the numbers into pairs which have average $\frac12n$.