# How to interpret the next expression of the Euler totient function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, totient-function

We know that the original definition of the Euler-totient function is as follows: Φ(n).
However, the other day I came across the following expression, which is nothing more than the following: Φd(n).
And my question would be, how can the above Euler-totient function be expressed by a formula?
Forgive me for not being able to describe the expression Φd(n) nicely, but I don’t know how to describe it properly.
Thank you for your answers!

Comment: How do you define $\varphi_d(n)$?

Comment: That is my question. :)

Comment: I don't think there is a commonly agreed definition. You might want to look up whatever textbooks you're using to get an desired answer.

Comment: Generalizations for Euler's totient function are usually for ideals in Dedekind rings, see [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52718/generalized-euler-phi-function).

Answer (score 1):

The question has more than one possible answer.

$1.$ The expression is $\Phi_d(n)$, where $\Phi_d(X)$ is the $d$-th cyclotomic polynomial. Here $\phi$ was confused with $\Phi$.

$2.$ Starting from $\phi(n)=\sum_{\stackrel{1\le k \le n}{(k,n)=1}} 1$ we could consider
$$
\phi_d(n)=\sum_{\stackrel{1\le k \le n}{(k,n)=1}} k^d.
$$
Then $\phi_0(n)=\phi(n)$.
However, this doesn't give something new for $d=1$, because $\phi_d(n)=\frac{1}{2}n\phi(n)$, see here:

[For $n > 2, n \in \mathbb{Z}$, show the sum of integers coprime to $n$ in the range $[1,n-1]$ is equal to $\frac{1}{2}n \phi(n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1305553/for-n-2-n-in-mathbbz-show-the-sum-of-integers-coprime-to-n-in-the-ra)

For $d=2$ we obtain
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{6} \varphi(n)
\left(2n^2 + (-1)^{|\mathcal{P}|}
\prod_{p\in \mathcal{P}} p\right).}$$